# Querying rows multiple times from ROOM database while using a Bitmap Type Converter class is crashing the App

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging

So I have Recycler View with a paging adapter, the recycler view list item has an imageView and a couple of text views. The data for the textViews are being retrieved by the adapter from another ROOM Database whereas the images for each those specific list items are being retrieved from another ImageHolder ROOM Database.

In the onBind method of the adapter in addition to binding the textViews there is a separate call to the ImageHolder ROOM Database for the associated image. The Recycler View has about 100 items and while the UI is scrolled quickly, about 100 queries are made to the ImageHolder Database. This works fine but it slows down the app as the user scrolls and crashes the app. How do I do avoid the crash?

Here is the code:

The data class

```
@Entity(tableName = IMAGE_HOLDER_TABLE)
data class ImageHolder(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var contentId: String = "",
    var imageBitmap : Bitmap,  // I am using a Converter class to convert a Bitmap to a ByteArray
    var timeStamp : Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
)
```

The Dao Interface

```
@Dao
interface ImageHolderDatabaseDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $IMAGE_HOLDER_TABLE WHERE contentId = :contentId")
    suspend fun getImageHolder(contentId : String): ImageHolder

    @Query("SELECT imageBitmap FROM $IMAGE_HOLDER_TABLE WHERE contentId = 
    :contentId")
    suspend fun getImage(contentId : String): Bitmap
}
```

The method to get the image in the Adapter's onBindViewHolder method

```
val imageHolderDatabase = ImageHolderDatabase.instance(getApplicationContext())
    val imageHolderDatabaseDao = imageHolderDatabase.databaseDao
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main +  
CoroutineName("notificationsAdapterCoroutine"))

    private fun populatePhotoFromLocalDb(senderUserId : String) {
        scope.launch {
            val imageBitmap = imageHolderDatabase.withTransaction {
                imageHolderDatabaseDao.getImageHolder(senderUserId)
            }

            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(imageBitmap.imageBitmap)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.black_color_rectangle)
                .apply(glideRequestOptionsForCache)
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(glideCrossFadeDuration))
                .listener(glideFinishedLoadingListener(senderUserId, true, null))
                .into(binding.image)
        }
    }
//I am using the Paging 3 adapter to populate the textViews from another Room Database
```

I realize there are 100 query calls made to the ImageHolder Room Database since there are 100 items in the Recycler View. I am using Glide but not using its Caching for now.

What is a memory-efficient way to do this?

Comment: As I understand you are doing 100 database queries to get 100 images? Why do not get all of them with one query and store them in an array which after that you can use to populate your RecyclerView?

Comment: Also you can add the stacktrace of the crash too.

Comment: Hi @hardartcore, the database fetches data from a Network database in batches of 20 at a time as the user scrolls so getting all 100 would be too expensive since all data would have to be downloaded over the network

Comment: It depends on how you are downloading it. As I understand you download all the images and save them in a database as byte array and then recreate them as bitmap object and pass to Glide?

Comment: Yes, download if the database is empty and the next time the activity is created and if the database has items then get data from the database itself without querying it from the network

Comment: I think your whole idea is wrong. Why do you need to download the whole image and save it as byte array in a database? Just save the url inside the database and than use Glide to download the image and show it inside the adapter. In this way at the beginning you will be downloading only text data, without any images.

Comment: @hardartcore, yes I realized the type converter from ByteArray to Bitmap is causing too much memory usage, I have now implemented exactly what you've suggested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type converter from ByteArray to Bitmap is causing too much memory usage, this is actually a good way to store images but the wrong use case for using the handy Type converters for ROOM (unless it's used in a non recyclerView adapter), I have instead changed the logic to store the downloadUrls only in the Room Db and using glide to load images via the download Url since glide has offline cache system built in, this logic works even with the internet being unavailable temporarily...